# Ubuntu 16.04 Toshiba Protege - Unable to mirror screen onto ASUS monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have just bought an ASUS PA278QV monitor. Since I have to spend long hours in front of a computer, I wanted to connect my laptop (TOSHIBA PORTEGE Z930-148), which has Ubuntu 16.04, to the monitor. I have used an HDMI cable, but unfortunately I cannot change the display settings, as the only option available is the built-in display. It doesn't detect other devices (neither monitor nor TV).
I'm not a computer expert, so I have no idea if this is a problem with the operating system or with the laptop itself.

Comment: The laptop has HDMI or are you using an adapter?

Comment: Laptop has HDMI. No idea why it's not working.